# Get extra value from activity that is not started from current activity

Tags: android

I know how to get results from another activity using `startActivityForResult` but the problem is that I have 3 activities A,B and C. The main activity is A, that back button on all activities should return there.

Now when we Open activity B from activity A, and then activity C from activity B. When the back button is pressed on the Activity C, How can I return the result to activity A?

Activity A:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            int result=data.getIntExtra("result", 0);
            SetNotification(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity C:

```
 //This works for activity B which is started directly from activity A
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", unreadCount);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Personally I would store it in a static variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When the back button is pressed on the Activity C, How can I return the result to activity A?"

Do not go back. Go forward, young grasshopper :P

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);

// FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK : If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.
// FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP: If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, 
// then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on 
// top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

intent.putExtra("result", unreadCount);

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
   returnIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   returnIntent.putExtra("result", unreadCount);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then you can fetch your Extras in A's onCreate().

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use onActivityResult() from Activity B to redirect the call to Activity A. Something like this:

```
// Activity B
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                // Get data from activity C
                int result = data.getIntExtra("result", 0);

                // Create intent with data from activity C
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);

                // Set the response
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ActivityB can pass this result to ActivityA when onActivityResult of ActivityB is called after pressing back of ActivityC. So ActivityB can do as follows:

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        int result=data.getIntExtra("result", 0);

       Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
       returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
       finish();
    }
}
```

}